# Incoming connection in NAT

Tags: networking, nat

A very basic question:

As per my understanding, a machine in an external network cannot initiate a connection to a machine behind a NAT router. Is there a way I can allow this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way is to do "port forwarding" on your NAT/NAPT device. There must be thousands of article and videos about port forwarding all over the web.

The harder way is SSH  But what I wrote above is a more direct answer to your question.